# Three js enabling shadow render slow

Tags: three.js

I am loading a building model to the scene using `GLTFLoader` and apply some texture, also Adding two PointLight source with shadow enabled. I am using self shadow for the building, that is the building itself should create shadow from light source.

But when I load the page, I am having some performance issue withe page, the frame rate is too slow on status and entire system behave hang. 
But if disable the shadow everything work as expected. Is this expected or I can improve it on coding.

Here is the working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n9eg3kox/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, stats;
var mesh;
var controls;
var BuildingObj;
var OutFloor;
var enableShadow = true; // if I make it false the code work fine   
var pointLight2, pointLight3;

function init() {

    var webglEl = document.getElementById('webgl');
    if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage(webglEl);
        alert("WebGL no Support");
        return;
    }

    THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 1.5);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = enableShadow;
    renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
    webglEl.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x555555, 1);

    var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.01, 2000);
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 4;
    camera.position.z = 30;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
    scene.add(axesHelper);

    var intensity = 5;
    var distance = 40;
    var decay = 1.0;

    pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, intensity);
    pointLight2.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 16, 16), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xfffdfb, emissive: 0xfffdfb, emissiveIntensity: 100 })));
    pointLight2.position.set(-60, 80, 40);
    pointLight2.castShadow = enableShadow;
    pointLight2.visible = true;
    pointLight2.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    pointLight2.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    scene.add(pointLight2);

    pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, intensity);
    pointLight3.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 16, 16), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xfffdfb, emissive: 0xfffdfb, emissiveIntensity: 100 })));
    pointLight3.position.set(60, 80, 40);
    pointLight3.castShadow = enableShadow;
    pointLight3.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    pointLight3.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    pointLight3.visible = true;
    scene.add(pointLight3);

    //var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 21 );
    //scene.add( light );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, webglEl);
    stats = new Stats();
    webglEl.appendChild(stats.dom);
    loadObject();
    animate();
}

function animate() {
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function loadObject() {

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
        //'./Model/GLTF/test.glb',
        './test/test.glb',
        function (gltf) {
            gltf.scene.traverse(function (node) {
                if (node.isGroup) {
                    if (node.name === "Building") {
                        BuildingObj = node;

                    } else if (node.name === "Cube") {
                        OutFloor = node;
                    }
                }
            });
            scene.add(OutFloor);
            scene.add(BuildingObj);
            applyMaterialToObject();
        },
        function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        },

        function (error) {
            console.log('An error happened---' + error);
        }
    );
}

function applyMaterialToObject(object) {

    for (var i = 0; i < BuildingObj.children.length; i++) {
        var obj = BuildingObj.children[i];
        var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ roughness: 0.8, metalness: 0.3, bumpScale: - 0.05, color: 0xffffff, });
        loadTexturesToMaterial(BuildingObj.children[i], material, "./test/brick.jpg", "./test/brick_b.jpg", "./test/brick_r.jpg", 25, 70, Math.PI / 2);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < OutFloor.children.length; i++) {
        var obj = OutFloor.children[i];
        var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.8, bumpScale: - 0.05, color: 0xffffff });
        loadTexturesToMaterial(obj, material, "./test/tile2.jpg", "./test/tile2_b.jpg", "./test/tile2_r.jpg", 35, 100, Math.PI / 2);
    }
}

function loadTexturesToMaterial(obj, material, map_img, bumpMap_img, roughnessMap_img, v_count, h_count, rotation) {

    obj.receiveShadow = enableShadow;
    obj.castShadow = enableShadow;
    obj.material = material;
    obj.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load(map_img, function (map) {
        map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.rotation = rotation;
        map.repeat.set(v_count, h_count);
        obj.material.map = map;
        obj.material.needsUpdate = true;
    });

    textureLoader.load(bumpMap_img, function (map) {
        map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.rotation = rotation;
        map.repeat.set(v_count, h_count);
        obj.material.bumpMap = map;
        obj.material.needsUpdate = true;
    });

    textureLoader.load(roughnessMap_img, function (map) {
        map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        map.rotation = rotation;
        map.repeat.set(v_count, h_count);
        obj.material.roughnessMap = map;
        obj.material.needsUpdate = true;
    });
}
```

Note: I have created the model using blender.

Edit: Texture and model link

https://github.com/SourceCodeZone/3D

Comment: How big is your `.glb` file? I'm writing this 2 minutes after clicking on the JSFiddle link, and the GLB is still loading.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, actually the link was broken to model and texture, now I have updated the fiddle. Also give  the link for accessing the model and texture. https://github.com/SourceCodeZone/3D